# notifications on windows RT

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I couldn't find this information, do we get notification callbacks when our app is running in background? I understand tiles will get updated, but if we can get callbacks in realtime, we can get our stuff done.

Im sure this is not possible in wp7, is there a way in RT metro app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes — please see [Raw notifications sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d) on MSDN.

Also, look at [Quickstart: Creating and registering a raw notification background task (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML) (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709906.aspx#register_your_background_task_in_your_app) article on MSDN.

**UPDATE:** For server-side implementation info you can try [another great quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868252.aspx).

Comment: Looks like, this is what i wanted. But they didn't include server code to test this out.

Comment: So, i've to make my own sample server to test this? i remember microsoft gave a sample server program in wp7 samples.

Comment: As I can see there are no samples containing server-side implementation. However, those step-by-step guides make it pretty ease to  implement everything by yourself.